# How to prevent bound Service from being destroyed while Activity's runtime changes (ex: orientation)

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a bound Service. An activity is binding it. It unbinds the Service on Activity's `onStop()` method.

The problem is, if runtime changes (for example, orientation change) happen to the Activity, then the Activity is recreated. So, `onStop()` method is called from the Activity, and the Activity unbinds the Service in that method, which results in destruction of the Service (and restarting of it).

I want to preserve the Service from being destroyed in the runtime changes while keeping Service stopping when the Activity is invisible. You could say that try `startService()` but it makes the Service not to stop when Activity is invisible. If I add stopService Activity's `onStop()`, then the result is the same as `bindService()` and `unbindService()`.

PostDelaying `unbindService()` in Acitivity's `onStop()` can solve this problem partly, but the delaying time will be arbitrary, and this prevents the Activity from getting GC for some time. I want a more clear solution.

I don't want solutions like `android:configChanges="orientation"` since there are other runtime changes as well, and it is a discouraged way of processing runtime changes.

In short, I want the Service to act like a Fragment that called `setRetainInstance(true)`. However, Fragments don't have something like `bindService()`. What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> However, Fragments don't have something like bindService().

But they can use `bindService()` from the `Application` context:

```
public class BshFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,
    ServiceConnection {
  private IScript service=null;
  private Button btn=null;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    btn=(Button)result.findViewById(R.id.eval);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn.setEnabled(false);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    return(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().getApplicationContext()
                 .bindService(new Intent(getActivity(),
                                         BshService.class), this,
                              Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().getApplicationContext().unbindService(this);
    disconnect();

    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    EditText script=(EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.script);
    String src=script.getText().toString();

    service.executeScript(src);
  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
    service=(IScript)binder;
    btn.setEnabled(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    disconnect();
  }

  private void disconnect() {
    service=null;
    btn.setEnabled(false);
  }
}
```

(as seen in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AdvServices/Binding), covered in [this book](http://commonsware.com/Android))

By using the `Application` context, we are able to use the same `Context` for binding and unbinding. By retaining the fragment, we can avoid unbinding and rebinding on a configuration change.

Personally, I just try to avoid the binding pattern. I am a fan of loosely-coupled interfaces, and so I prefer using services via the command pattern and `startService()`.

Comment: I didn't come up with the Application Context. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Call startService in onCreate and then onStop

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if (!isChangingConfigurations ())
    {
          // call stopService
    }
}
```

Comment: This will cause a bound service to leak it's connection.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to keep alive a only-bound service during runtime changes could be to define in the service class a method like `keepAlive`:

```
public void keepAlive(boolean value) {
    if (value) startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getClass()));
    else stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    keepAlive(false);
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return true;
}
```

In `onRebind()` the only-bound service status is resetted.